# $\tan x= \cot (x+\phi)$ for some $\phi$

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

Suppose we graphed the equation $ y = \tan x $. Is it possible to describe this graph with an equation of the form $ y = \cot (x + \phi) $, for some number $ \phi $? Why or why not?

Comment: The graph of $\cot x$ is always downward sloping and the graph of $\tan x$ is always upward sloping.  $x+\phi$ is a lateral translation and won't fundamentally change the direction of slope.  However,  $\tan x =\cot (\frac{\pi}{2} - x)$

Comment: @DougM -- Yes, I understand. I typed up an answer with a more rigorous proof, though. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I've asked you before, but would you like to join my [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art)?  I've seen you often, and it appears you are interested in topics at least I can talk about.

Comment: For the benefit of search engines: this problem appeared in Trigonometry by Gelfand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

No; there is not $ \phi $ such that $ y = \tan x $ can be expressed as $ y = \cot (x + \phi) $.

---

### Proof 1 - Algebraic & Rigorous

---

**Step 1:** Find the relation between $ \phi $ and $ x $.

$ \tan x = \cot (x + \phi) $

$ \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{\cos (x + \phi)}{\sin (x + \phi)} $

$ \cos (x + \phi)\cos x = \sin (x + \phi)\sin x $

$ \cos (x + \phi)\cos x - \sin (x + \phi)\sin x = 0 $

$ \cos ((x + \phi) + x) = 0 $

$ \cos (2x + \phi) = 0 $

$ 2x + \phi = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi $ (let $k$ be any integer)

$ \phi = -2x + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi $

---

**Step 2:** Understand the relation between $ \phi $ and $ x $.

Sin $ \phi $ depends on $ x $, which is variable, there cannot be a constant $ \phi $ to satisfy $ \tan x = \cot (x + \phi) $.

---

### Proof - Graphically & Improper

---

**Step 1:** Graph the functions $ y_0 = \tan x$ and $ y_1 = \cot x $.

*(others are welcome to add images of some graphs)*

---

**Step 2:** Start shifting the function $ y_1 $ along the x-axis.

Note that you will never be able to superimpose $ y_1 $ over $ y_0 $.

Answer (score 2):

The function
$$
f(x)=\tan x-\cot(x+\varphi)
$$
is defined on an open set and everywhere differentiable (on its domain). Also
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}+\frac{1}{\sin^2(x+\varphi)}>0
$$
for every $x$ in the domain of $f$. Being a strictly increasing function on every interval included in the domain (which is a union of open intervals), $f$ is clearly not identically zero.

---

Shorter proof: $\tan 0=\cot\varphi$ gives $\varphi=\pi/2+k_1\pi$; $\tan\pi/4=\cot(\pi/4+\varphi)$ gives $\cot(\pi/4+\varphi)=1$, so $\varphi=k_2\pi$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If we had $\tan x=\cot(x+\phi)$, then the graph of $\tan x$ could be translated into the graph of $\cot x$, which it obviously cannot.

But compare the graphs below. I have translated them so that their asymptotes line up, but to bring them into coincidence we would also need to reflect about the $x$ axis. Of course, we can do that, which gives us the rather similar relation $$\tan x=-\cot(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$$

[image]

[image]